# Remove all files with a prefix except the one of the largest size

Tags: command-line, files, wildcards

What is the best way to remove all the files in the current directory with some prefix, except the file with this prefix but having the largest size among all the files with this prefix?

(In the case when the largest one is not unique, just randomly keep one of them and remove the others.)

For example, the current directory contains the following files:

```
-rw-rw----  1 user user 3468 Jan 01 00:00 filea
-rw-rw----  1 user user 3434 Jan 01 00:00 pre_0
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user 9769 Jan 01 00:00 fileb
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user 1950 Jan 01 00:00 filec
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user 8654 Jan 01 00:00 pre_1
-rw-rw----  1 user user 6508 Jan 01 00:00 pre_2
```

After running the command or the script to remove all the files with prefix "pre_" except the largest one, the current directory should be listed as:

```
-rw-rw----  1 user user 3468 Jan 01 00:00 filea
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user 9769 Jan 01 00:00 fileb
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user 1950 Jan 01 00:00 filec
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user 8654 Jan 01 00:00 pre_1
```

Comment: I'm just wondering, what is the real world application for this? Is it managing log files, or files in a photo gallery that were resized into many different sizes (and now you want to delete the smaller files), or something else?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, the application in my case is log/record files management. The other application on photo gallery management you mentioned is also very interesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a combination of few utilities:

```
stat -c '%s %n' pre_* | sort -k1,1rn | tail -n +2 | cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs rm
```

Assuming GNU system and no unusual filenames.

- `stat` gets the filesize and name separated by space for all `pre_*` files
- `sort` sorts the file according to the file size, with highest sized one goes to top
- `tail -n +2` gets the rest of the files apart from the max sized one
- `cut -d' ' -f2` gets the file name only, and `rm` (`xargs rm`) does the removal

Comment: Isn't going to work with filenames with spaces. Would break at the stage of `cut`. At least that stage can be fixed if `cut` call is replaced by `sed 's@^[^ ]\+ @@'`. Not sure if `xargs` will work correctly.

Comment: @Ruslan It would be broken at `stat` stage then, thats why i mentioned _no unusual filenames_

Comment: Why? Doesn't the shell glob expand to quoted/escaped names?

Comment: `stat` can not send output as NUL separated, thats why..

Comment: Well, I understand that newline in filename is unusual, but why would you assume that space is unusual?

Comment: @Ruslan Fair enough..edited..

Comment: `ls -S`, also a GNU extension is slightly more portable.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for the caveats.  I have edited the answer to remove that portion.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Didn't think of that. Edited. Thanks.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Upvoted your answer. Also just curious, is there any somewhat straight way using `bash` and utilities?

Comment: @heemayl, see edit of my answer.

Answer (score 7):

With `zsh`:

```
rm -f pre*(OL[2,-1])
```

- `OL`: reverse order by size
- `[2,-1]`: second to last only

The equivalent with `bash` and GNU utilities would be something like:

```
eval "files=($(LC_ALL=C ls --quoting-style=shell-always -dS ./pre*))"
rm -f "${files[@]:1}"
```

You may want to limit it to regular files, as the size for non-regular files has generally not much relevance:

```
rm -f pre*(.OL[2,-1])
```

(no direct bash+GNU equivalent). You may want to include symlinks to regular files and consider the size of the target of the symlinks:

```
rm -f pre*(-.OL[2,-1])
```

With `ls`, add the `-L` option to consider the size of the targets of symlinks.

Comment: Wow, perhaps there really is something to `zsh`...I haven't actually learned it up to now.  Haven't found any good starting point, either.

Comment: @Wildcard, of course there is :-). You could start with [the User's Guide](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide.html).